# Xilium CefGlue - How to get a result from javascript?

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefglue

In C# with Wilium CefGlue, I call JavaScript code like this

```
browser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScript("return 1;", null, 0);
```

But `ExecuteJavaScript()` is a void method.

How can I get the return value from JavaScript code?

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript Integration](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration)

> The **ExecuteJavaScript()** function can be used to interact with functions and variables in the frame's JS context. In order to return values from JS to the client application consider using **Window Binding** or **Extensions**.